# The multi-part identifier could not be bound - SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, subquery, inner-join

Schema:

```
create table TableA (A1 int)
create table TableB (B1 int, B2 int)
create table TableC (C1 int)
```

Problematic query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.B1=a.A1
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM TableC c
            WHERE c.C1=b.B1 ORDER BY c.C1) d ON d.C2=b.B2
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.Foo=d.C1
```

Building this schema and running the query in SQLFiddle under SQL Server 2008 results in:

```
The multi-part identifier "b.B1" could not be bound.: SELECT * FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.B1=a.A1 INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableC c WHERE c.C1=b.B1 ORDER BY c.C1) d ON d.C2=b.B2
```

**Using CROSS APPLY instead of INNER JOIN for the subquery fixes the issue**

What's the problem?

Edit: I added "TOP 1" that was part of the real query and it's a relevant part of the problem.

Edit2: Further information about the problem.

Comment: OK. Look at your subquery. You filter by C1 then ORDER BY C1. What's meaning?I think you must `ORDER BY` C2.

Comment: This is an abstraction of the real query

Comment: But you distort logic. See my updated answer.

Comment: Using CROSS APPLY (or OUTER APPLY in my case instead of a LEFT JOIN)... resolved this issue for me!

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` was new to me, but solved my challenge!  Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't reference from `JOIN` clause to another part of JOIN.

Use this instead.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON b.B1=a.A1
INNER JOIN TableC c
    ON d.C2=b.B2
      AND c.C1=b.B1
```

**EDITED**

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.B1=a.A1
WHERE b.B2 = (SELECT TOP 1 c.C2 
               FROM TableC c
               WHERE c.C1=b.B1 ORDER BY c.C1)
```

For further use of `TableC` in JOIN-s you can use this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b
        ON b.B1=a.A1
    INNER JOIN
       (
           SELECT
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C2) RN,
               C2
               --, other columns fromTableC if needed
           FROM TableC
       ) CC
     ON b.B2 = CC.C2
       AND CC.RN = 1
```

Comment: What if the "SELECT TOP 1" is needed in further inner joins?

Comment: Using "ROW_NUMBER()" is criminal.

Comment: `Using "ROW_NUMBER()" is criminal.` Why?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot access an alias from a join inside of another joined subquery. You will need to use the following which joins the subquery on two columns/tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b 
  ON b.B1=a.A1
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM TableC c
) d 
  ON d.C2=b.B2
  AND d.C1 = b.B1
```

Or this can be written as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b 
  ON b.B1=a.A1
INNER JOIN TableC c
  ON c.C2=b.B2
  AND c.C1 = b.B1
```

Comment: `You cannot access an alias inside of a subquery.` I don't think so. `SELECT * FROM Table1 T1 WHERE someColumn IN (SELECT someColumn FROM Table2 WHERE T1.Id = Table1_Id )`

Comment: From a join inside of another joined sub query - was their point I believe